# Bootstrap Form Groups not inline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is that the "Category" button and the input bar with the "GO!" button are not on the same line as each other.

Here is a code snippet:

```
<form class="form" role="form"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Category <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is what it currently looks like:

[image]

As you can see they are both on separate lines.

Comment: If you want an inline form, why aren't you using the `form-inline` class on your `<form>`?

Comment: @cvrebert Because it don't work only with this : http://www.bootply.com/120676

Comment: Can you do this? http://www.bootply.com/120677

Comment: @Skelly is in the truth, look at the doc http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline => Requires custom widths
Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap. To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form controls used within.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it working using Skelly's Method. I was doing the same thing as Jahnux when i using form-inline which is why i scrapped it.

Edit, for some reason it's bunching together and leaving a space to the left of the category button when placed inside a container http://imgur.com/aUmqI1a

Answer (score 0):

I thing You Should write

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    ....
</form>
```

If You are write the form class (.form) in your css file. Then Ok. Because I think There is not any classes in Bootstrap.css which Name is Form(.form). It's

1st.

```
<form></form>
```

2nd.

```
<form class = "form-inline"></form>
```

3rd.

```
<form class = "form-horizontal"></form>
```